# Find Ongoing and Upcoming Events

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have programmed a system which allows administrator to add bacthes. (Basic details + Date of Start and End date). The date format is YYYY/MM/DD. Type : VARCHAR (50). Shoud I use different type (Need expert advice)

I need to list the upcoming and ongoing batches

This is the query which i think would return the ongoing projects

```
SELECT * FROM PROGRAMMES WHERE 'startdate' <= '$currentdate' AND 'enddate' > '$currentdate'
```

and for Upcoming projects

```
`SELECT * FROM PROGRAMMES WHERE 'startdate' >= '$currentdate`'
```

But I'm unsure about the results.. Since the value is stored in VARCHAR (Would it fetch my required results).. Should i use a different data type for date.. If so please specify

I couldn't understand much from PHP tutorials as everywhere its different.. Could someone guide me with the most commonly used method.

Thanks

Comment: MySQL has a DATE and DATETIME data type that you can use for this kind of stuff

Comment: You should always store the date in mysql native date data types `date`, `datetime` or `timestamp` the format is `YYYY-mm-dd` now which format is your input `$currentdate`

Comment: I haven't started adding batches to db as of now.. So I am open to any format... From what i've read everyone reccommends using YYYY/MM/DD format..

Comment: change the data type to `date` and its in `yyyy-mm-dd` format and make sure you enter values in the same format.

Comment: yeah sure would do that... Would the conditional operator work perfect then?

Comment: yes it should work perfect then if the input values are in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` and more over you can use the inbulit functions like `now()` `curdate()` etc for the comparison.

Comment: Also, make sure your column names are not quoted. `'startdate'` will always be larger than any date string (e.g. `'2050/12/31'`) because `'s' > '2'`. You want `"startdate >= '$currentdate'"`, without single quotes around `startdate`; and as other suggest, do use `DATE` type. Also, obligatory link: Beware [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method I use is the following:

- always use `DATETIME` type for datetime.
- always store dates in single timezone (UTC as base if project will need to show date in different TZ).

You can compare `DATETIME` columns using operators `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`, `=`.
It is very easy to use and is definitely better then storing date as `VARCHAR`.

For example, you could find events which have finished last day  like this:

```
... WHERE date_column < NOW() AND date_column > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Also, this might help you [Best practice for storing the date in MySQL from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116529/best-practice-for-storing-the-date-in-mysql-from-php)

Comment: that worked great...NOW() function is new to me... I never knew that..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM PROGRAMMES WHERE startdate <= $currentdate AND enddate > $currentdate
```

Comment: I hope you didn't get my question?? 

I was asking for data type for storing date