# Date Counting PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm building a task list. I have two tables in my DB. Template and Tasks
The templates are structured like so

```
id, task_name, function, text, days_to_action

1, Touch Base, call, Call to touch base, 7
```

The tasks table is structured like this:

```
id, task_name, function, text, due_date
1, Touch Base, call, Call to touch base, 02:06:2016
```

The due date is calculated with this formula ($set_days is grabbing  days_to_action):

```
$dueDate = date('d:m:Y', strtotime('+'.$set_days.' days'));
```

As you can see I am using Australian date format. To do the right thing I have included this at the top of all of my pages:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');
```

On my page I am trying to display tasks that are due today or overdue.

```
$today = date('d:m:Y');
$task_list = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE id='$linkid' && time_due <= '$today' ORDER BY datetime DESC");
```

The bug I have found is when the days roll over to a new month (like the example above) my code thinks 02/06/2016 (dd/mm/yyyy) is a date that comes before 28/05/2016.

Can the database only use American format? Is there an option to switch to Australian? Is there a step I am missing?
B

Comment: Update the column to be `DATE` type, and you can rely on MySQL to do those calculations for you.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I have updated the collumn. It wiped out my inputs as I guess they are invalid. I will try to fix the submission and see if that works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, for storing date values, DATE datatype should be use, as it would be convenient to maintain and for data retrieval.

MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

You can easily change the format at application level in PHP, for display or other operational purpose, but you should always Push/Pull the records in MySQL with DATE datatype i.e. 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

You may change the datatype by using:

```
ALTER TABLE task CHANGE due_date due_date DATE
```

References

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html
- http://www.developwebsites.net/choose-optimal-mysql-data-type/
- [Best practice for storing the date in MySQL from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116529/best-practice-for-storing-the-date-in-mysql-from-php)